# [UWP][Collection] Tap the last item to add

Tags: uwp

I saw that in the latest version of [Microsoft Journal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/journal-a-microsoft-garage-project/9n318r854rhh), we can tap the last item to add a page, is there a standard way to implement this pattern in UWP?
[image]

**Updates**

I was asking for the pattern with which we can tap the last item (ADD A PAGE +) to add an item to the end of the collection of the page grid view at the right side, not the page at the left side.

Comment: It is not clear how it is implemented in this app. But we could use [scroll view control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/scroll-controls) to accomplish similar effects. You could set keydown event for scroll view to monitor [keyboard input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-events#defining-a-keyboard-event-handler), when the keydown event is triggered by TAP key, you could add a panel to the scroll view.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Ah, I didn't mean the left part (but it's also a point that interests me), I was asking for the page grid view at the right side, they managed to implement the pattern with which we tap the last item (ADD A PAGE +) and add an item to the grid view then re-add the ADD A PAGE item to the end of the collection. However, thx anyway for your answer :)

Comment: You could bind a data source named MyItems, then you can set the last item of MyItems as an Add panel. When you click the last item, you could insert the item before the last item, such as MyItems.insert(MyItems.Count, panel).